# can i use steeltoe eureka service discovery in a grpc client/server

Tags: .net-core, steeltoe

i have a grpc service where i want to add it to service discovery and grpc client be able to discover it
but i could not find anything online to help me with that.

I am using steeltoe with eureka

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Steeltoe doesn't have explicit support for GRPC, but at this point it doesn't appear to be necessary (because it does work).

See [this issue](https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Steeltoe/issues/433) for more info and/or join the conversation